# Indirect modification of overloaded element has no effect on array

Tags: php

Using Laravel 5.4. Why can't I update this field in an array?

In my controller I have a protected field `$game`.

I then fetch its data

```
$this->game = GameProgress::where('id', '=', $id)->lockForUpdate()->first();
```

Some of the properties are `JSON` columns, such as the `regions` field, a part of the collection is:

```
 #attributes: array:22 [
    "id" => 13
    "name" => "DEBUGfdsf"
    "creator_id" => 1
    "game_id" => 1
    "difficulty_id" => 2
    "players_total" => 2
    "round_number" => 1
    "stage_name" => "setup"
    "active_player_id" => 2
    "active_player_turn_id" => 1
    "winner_id" => 0
    "game_points" => 0
    "locked" => 0
    "players" => "[{"id": 2, "name": "The Damage Hot", "cards": [{"id": 3, "type": "Armored", "image": "chad.png", "strength": 4, "region_id": 10, "type_image": "armored.png", "region_owned_adder": 2}, {"id": 2, "type": "Infantry", "image": "china.png", "strength": 2, "region_id": 13, "type_image": "infantry.png", "region_owned_adder": 1}, {"id": 2, "type": "Infantry", "image": "kazakhstan.png", "strength":........
```

I then access / update the data like this:

```
$this->game['regions'][$region_id - 1]['strength'] = $region_adder + $this->game['regions'][$region_id - 1]['strength'];
```

But I get this:

```
Indirect modification of overloaded element of App\Models\GameProgress has no effect
```

I cannot seem to work around this. How do I manipulate the content of fields in the arrays?

Comment: Seems `$this->game` is a `GameProgress` instance. What is its API? Does it offer a way to manipulate the data?

Comment: $this->game is a protected variable available to controller globally. It contains an instance of the GameProgress collection.

Answer (score 1):

Insanity setting in. I was accessing a collection as an array. Adding the `->toArray()` to the record collection fixed it.

```
$this->game = GameProgress::where('id', '=', session()->get('game.id'))->lockForUpdate()->first()->toArray();
```